# scipy.sparse package is multithreads/multiprocess or not

Tags: python, multithreading, scipy

I am using `scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu` and `scipy.sparse.linalg.bicgstab` to solve Ax=b. I observed my CPU usage sometimes is around 50%. My CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2@3.40GHZ which has 4 cores and 8 logical processors. I would like to know whether those two functions I use is multithread/multiprocessor, since if it is single thread/core, the CPU usage should be around 12.5%, right?
Thanks!

Edit:

My code is below:

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg as spla
import scipy
import scipy.io as io
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

f="memplus.mtx"
A=io.mmread(f)
x=np.ones(A.shape[1])*0.99
b = np.dot( A.todense(), np.ones(A.shape[1]) ) 

lu=spla.spilu(A=A)

M_x = lambda x: lu.solve(x)

ndim = x.shape[0]
M = scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator((ndim, ndim), M_x)

a, info=spla.bicgstab(A, b.T, x0=x, tol=1e-12, maxiter=10000, M=M)
```

Answer (score 0):

These routines are not themselves parallelized. However, if you are using a multithreaded BLAS library such as ATLAS or Openblas, which is likely, several linear algebra operations in the routines are parallelized. Therefore, they benefit from multiple cores.

Comment: I don't think I use multithread BLAS library. I will update the code in the question.

Comment: The multithreaded BLAS library is used internally by spilu and bicgstab -- not directly by your Python code. If you are using windows and prebuilt binaries, it is not unlikely they are multithreaded.

Comment: I am using enthought canopy. I would like to know how can I check whether it is multithread/multicore or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@p.v is correct. You must link scipy/numpy to a multithreaded blas library to take advantage of your multiple cores.

On a side note, I'm assuming that you are using Linux. Within Linux, when watching CPU utilization, the percentage you see is per core. 50% would mean that half of one core is being used. If you have 8 cores, then you should see CPU usage around 800% if all 8 are being used fully.

Comment: I am using windows and I think in windows if CPU usage is around 50%, that means I am using multithreads/multicores.