# scipy slow sparse matrix solver

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

I can't seem to get a benefit out of scipy's CG and sparse matrix algorithms.

When I try to solve this banded matrix equation

```
import time
import scipy.sparse.linalg as ssla
import scipy.sparse as ss
import numpy as np

size = 3000
x = np.ones(size)
A = ss.diags([1, -2, 1], [-1, 0, 1], shape=[size, size]).toarray()
print 'cond. nr.:{}'.format(np.linalg.cond(A))
b = np.dot(A, x)

start_time = time.clock()
sol = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
error = np.sum(np.abs(sol - x))
print 'LU time, error:', elapsed_time, error

start_time = time.clock()
sol, info = ssla.bicg(A, b, tol=1e-12)
elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
error = np.sum(np.abs(sol - x))
print 'CG time, ret code, error:', elapsed_time, info, error
```

it takes about 20 times as long as the LU solver. From what I understood, CG isn't that much more costly than LU, even if it has to use all N iterations to reach the result. So I expected it to be at least as fast, but actually a lot faster, due to the prior knowledge about the bandedness. Does it have to do with the condition number to be so bad?

In case of a dense matrix

```
import time
import scipy.sparse.linalg as ssla
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 1000
x = np.ones(size)
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.random_integers(-size, size,
                              size=(size, size))
print 'cond. nr.:{}'.format(np.linalg.cond(A))
b = np.dot(A, x)

start_time = time.clock()
sol = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
error = np.sum(np.abs(sol - x))
print 'LU time, error:', elapsed_time, error

start_time = time.clock()
sol, info = ssla.bicg(A, b, tol=1e-12)
elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
error = np.sum(np.abs(sol - x))
print 'CG time, ret code, error:', elapsed_time, info, error
```

I don't get convergence at all. In this case, the condition number of A doesn't seem that large, but then I don't have a lot of experience with this kind of thing.

Comment: Convergence also depends on the initial guess you choose.  If you happen to pick the correct answer as the starting point you'll converge in one iteration; make a poor selection and you may require many more iterations.  It's not just about the matrix and its conditioning.

Comment: A `(1000, 1000)` matrix is trivially small. Try something bigger and sparser.

Comment: Adding x0=x to the bicg call in my second example does'nt fix the problem. When reducing the size to 10, I get a valid result with bicg without starting guess. Adding x0=x in gives me a wrong solution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You create `A` using

```
A = ss.diags([1, -2, 1], [-1, 0, 1], shape=[size, size]).toarray()
```

That call to `.toarray()` converts the sparse matrix to a regular numpy array.  So you are passing a regular array to a sparse solver, which means the sparse solver can't take advantage of any sparsity structure.
If you pass the original sparse matrix to the solver, it is much faster.

For solving a banded system, a fast alternative is [`scipy.linalg.solve_banded`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_banded.html). (There is also [`scipy.linalg.solveh_banded`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solveh_banded.html) for Hermitian systems.)

Here's your example, but with the sparse matrix passed to the sparse solver.  Also included is a solution computed using `scipy.linalg.solve_banded`, which turns out to be *much* faster than the other two methods.

```
import time
import scipy.sparse.linalg as ssla
import scipy.sparse as ss
from scipy.linalg import solve_banded
import numpy as np

size = 3000
x = np.ones(size)
S = ss.diags([1, -2, 1], [-1, 0, 1], shape=[size, size])
A = S.toarray()
print 'cond. nr.:{}'.format(np.linalg.cond(A))
b = np.dot(A, x)

start_time = time.clock()
sol = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
error = np.sum(np.abs(sol - x))
print 'LU time, error          :  %9.6f    %g' % (elapsed_time, error)

start_time = time.clock()
sol, info = ssla.bicg(S, b, tol=1e-12)
elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
error = np.sum(np.abs(sol - x))
print 'CG time, ret code, error:  %9.6f %2d %g' % (elapsed_time, info, error)

B = np.empty((3, size))
B[0, :] = 1
B[1, :] = -2
B[2, :] = 1
start_time = time.clock()
sol = solve_banded((1, 1), B, b)
elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
error = np.sum(np.abs(sol - x))
print 'solve_banded time, error:  %9.6f    %g' % (elapsed_time, error)
```

Output:

```
cond. nr.:3649994.05818
LU time, error          :   0.858295    4.05262e-09
CG time, ret code, error:   0.552952  0 6.7263e-11
solve_banded time, error:   0.000750    4.05262e-09
```

Comment: There's something else that I'm observing. I'm currently running the LU solve, and it is using four out of my eight processors. I didn't expect it to do MP at all, but now I'm wondering why it's not using 100%. Is it the  default that only half the # of procs are used (i.e. is that something I can influence) or are all eight used only to 50% due to the implementation? I found a link that touches upon that question, but it doesn't seem to be answered fully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751093/scipy-sparse-package-is-multithreads-multiprocess-or-not